# Extract string of dynamic length when the indicator of completion exists in multiple instances. Postgres

Tags: postgresql, extract, greenplum

So if I have a varchar length string column let's call ID(samples below):

```
97.128.39.256.1460854333288493
25.365.49.12.13454154815132
346.45.156.354.1523425161233
```

I want to grab, like a left in excel, everything to the left of the **4th** period. How do i create a dynamic string to find the fourth instance of a period?

I know substring is a start but not sure how to write in the dynmic length that exists

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres? That makes a huge difference. Greenplum is based on  very old version of Postgres.

Comment: greenplum unfortunately...-.-

Comment: you mean Greenplum fortunately.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
mydb=> select regexp_replace('97.128.39.256.1460854333288493', E'^((?:\\d+\\.){3}\\d+).+$', E'\\1');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 97.128.39.256
(1 row)

Time: 0.634 ms
```

Comment: Does that only work with direct values? When I tried to replace the string with the column name it didn't change

{
select regexp_replace(id, '^((?:\d+\.){3}\d+).+$', '\1') regexp_replace
FROM A
LIMIT 3
}

Comment: Sorry about that.  That was on PostgreSQL.  Running this in GPDB, it changes slightly:

Comment: gpadmin=# select id, regexp_replace(id, E'^((?:\\d+\\.){3}\\d+).+$', E'\\1') repl from test;
                   id               |      repl
    --------------------------------+----------------
     25.365.49.12.13454154815132    | 25.365.49.12
     346.45.156.354.1523425161233   | 346.45.156.354
     97.128.39.256.1460854333288493 | 97.128.39.256
    (3 rows)
    
    Time: 22.550 ms

Comment: :DD Thank you! That worked great!! I really need to understand this regexp. Thanks so much!

Comment: Let me try to help.  The E'...' is just saying the following string contains escape chars. The '^' means "start of string"; the opening '(' starts a capturing group, which will later be referenced by the '\\1', to pull out all that matched within that '( ... )'; the '(?:\\d+\\.){3}' is a non-capturing group which has one or more digits followed by a period, and this is repeated 3 times; then the '\\d+' says to capture more digits, then the ')' is the end of the stuff you want to grab; finally, the '.+$' is just "the rest, to the end".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest for someone else to read:

```
select split_part(i, '.', 1) || '.' || 
       split_part(i, '.', 2) || '.' || 
       split_part(i, '.', 3) || '.' || 
       split_part(i, '.', 4) 
from (select '97.128.39.256.1460854333288493' as i) as sub;
```

Or if you don't like split_part and prefer to use arrays:

```
select array_to_string((string_to_array(i, '.'))[1:4], '.') 
from (select '97.128.39.256.1460854333288493' as i) as sub;
```

I think the array example is a bit harder to grasp at first glance but both work.

Updated answer based on revised question to also convert the Unix timestamp to a Greenplum timestamp:

```
select 'epoch'::timestamp + '1 second'::interval * 
       (split_part(i, '.', 5)::numeric/1000000) as event_time, 
       array_to_string((string_to_array(i, '.'))[1:4], '.') as ip_address 
from (
       select '97.128.39.256.1460854333288493' as i
     ) as sub;
```

Comment: .... Thank you Jon. 

Thank you, and triple thank you. You are the man. You're right the array one isn't immediately intuitive but it looks cleaner. I 'll be reading documentation on it to learn more about this function.

Comment: Hi @Jon-roberts, one quick question is if I am trying to embed your array suggestion into syntax that already has a defined level of precision, i get an error "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision". Is there a way to around it?

Sample of where I'm incorporating your function:

{

SELECT
TO_TIMESTAMP(substring(i from char_length (length(array_to_string((string_to_array(i, '.'))[1:4], '.')))+2 for 10)::float)::date as Date

}

Comment: 97.128.39 can't convert from a string to a float.  Is this string representing a date format somehow?  If so, what does each number represent?

Comment: So with the varchar string of 'i', is a mix of elements where the first part is an IP address, second part is a unix time string and finally another id. I was using your array to grab the first part (IP), which i then applied the length function to get the char count so I could tell the substring the starting point I want to actually extract the unix number. The to_timestamp and date was to then translate that unix time stamp into a consumable date.
Should I use other method? Thank you again for the followup!

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (s) as ( values
    ('97.128.39.256.1460854333288493'),
    ('25.365.49.12.13454154815132'),
    ('346.45.156.354.1523425161233')
)
select a[1] || '.' || a[2] || '.' || a[3] || '.' || a[4]
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(s, '\.')
    from t
) t (a)
;
    ?column?    
----------------
 97.128.39.256
 25.365.49.12
 346.45.156.354
```

Comment: Hi Clodoaldo, 

Thanks for your input! Question on the first section. I assume I simply cannot use the

with t (id) 
and then immediately into this regexp split to array item? or how would I use the regex if I am  breaking apart the column name? 

If I just run the middle section starting from select a[1], my output is triple zeroes.